# Facebook gives diffrent like count for same url in php sdk and graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I am using php sdk fql and graph api both for counting facebook likes. When I pass url like http://mydemowebsite.com/city/id-12345.html it gives me correct count but when I pass url like
http://m.mydemowebsite.com/city/id-12345.html to both the apis, its giving me different like count, Although it is the same page. It also shows same count on browser for both the links.

Comment: Not to be too rude, but does that really matter?

Comment: @jcolebrand Of course it does matter. One can want to understand **why** theses counts are not the same to be able to interpretate the results of the queries.

Comment: @Quentin I respectfully disagree. He says "for this it gives me the correct count but that other count is wrong" ... how does he know?

Comment: He can not know about what count is right or wrong (or even if there is something wrong) but his wish to understand is praiseworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Like Counts unique identifier is the URL, you maybe able to get around this but going to Facebook App Edit Settings and under website set the site domain to mydemowebsite.com. this allows for any subdomains of mydemowebsite.com to use the facebook api.